# How to connect external MS SQL server database from container

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I'm new in Docker and we are migrating our working ASP.NET CORE app to Docker in company

Problem is I did't find any releated topics about how to connect to external already existing MS SQL server [not in docker image] database from container.
All topics are about connecting to official [Image of MS SQL-Server](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server)[which I don't need].

I wrote Dockerfile and application running but there no connection to SQL Server

Please give me correct direction with topics or hints thank you!

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000 //port to app
EXPOSE 1433 //SQL-Server port


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY UploadCore/UploadCore.csproj UploadCore/
RUN dotnet restore UploadCore/UploadCore.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/UploadCore
RUN dotnet build UploadCore.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish UploadCore.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "UploadCore.dll"]
```

I'm running my app as below

`docker run -it  --rm -p 5000:5000 -p 1433:1433 --name UploadCore my-app_test:4.5`

**Error:**

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
      An error occurred using the connection to database 'MIS_REPORTS' on server 'server02'.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid: Connection string is not valid)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover, SqlAuthenticationMethod authType)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, DbConnectionPool pool)
```

Comment: The docker container needs outgoing network connectivity to the SQL Server. First go to the host that the docker container is running on and confirm you can connect to the SQL Server.

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to a Microsoft SQL Server? Port 1541 is typically used for an Oracle TNS listener. The default port for Microsoft SQL Server instances is 1433.

Comment: Aside... `EXPOSE` is used to expose services running inside the container for access by things outside the container. Do you have a service listening on port 1541 inside the container?

Comment: In your error message you have just a base host name `server02`; in a Docker context this will probably be picked up by the Docker-internal DNS resolver and resolved to a container name.  Does using a fully-qualified DNS name `server02.example.com` work better?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes I checked with telnet and it's successfull

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid How we configure outgoing network? Advice please

Comment: @DavidMaze makes a good point. Your error says _The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct_ Likely your docker container can't resolve a server name called `server02`. Please confirm that you have a _SQL Server_ running on port 1541. As already auggested try using a fully qualified name (server02.something.something) or, for troubleshooting, try the IP address. Also try PING and TELNET command from within the dociker container to work out what connectivity you have.

Comment: Reading the docs, it sounds like Docker for Linux works differently to window or mac. So whic hone are you using? Also is your docker container running on Server02` or a different host?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid @DavidMaze You are true LEGENDS. ``server02.example.com`` and port ``1433`` resolved issue.

Comment: @DavidMaze You are true LEGEND.

Comment: So I guess your telnet must have used port 1433 to be successful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker provides its own internal DNS service that can do things like resolve other container names as host names.  It looks like you've configured your database location as a bare host name `server02`.  This hits the Docker DNS resolver first, and it tries to resolve it as a container name; when that fails, that's why you're getting the error you do.

In different environments you can tell this apart from different kinds of errors by error messages like "name resolution failed" or "no such host"; this is different from an error message like "connection refused" or "connection reset by peer".

You can resolve this by using a fully-qualified domain name (FQDN) as your database location; for example, `server02.example.com` instead of just `server02`.  Since that doesn't look like a container name, it will cause Docker to forward the DNS request to your normal name server.